# How to handle different paths to one same document?

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

In MS Access I would like to link to a single document. However, the path to this document is not equal for each user. Note that there are **no multiple documents** on different servers.

See the image below. For some users the path location is 'H:/test/template.docx' and for another user this is 'Z:/test/template.docx'
There are two versions, the H and the Z disk.

How can I fix this? Do I need some VBA coding perhaps?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, and translations (you're using a command button?).

You can use the UNC (Universal Naming Convention) address.

In `File Explorer` (Open with `Windows Key + E`) in the `Folders` pane you'll see that H drive is mapped to a server & folder.

This is displayed as `somefolder on 'some_server' (H:)` or `somefolder on 'some_server\some other folder' (H:)`.

Use this in your Hyperlink Address:
`\\some_server\some other folder\somefolder\test\template.docx`
This address will be the same for all users.

Comment: Ah good, you got it working - replied to your first comment, which you then edited, so deleted my comment and was going to post another but you sorted it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, after some more try and error I found the correct path location:) Thanks!